# matrixStats::rowQuantiles gives NAs and returns the same value for multiple quartiles

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the 1st and 3rd quartiles for each row in my data frame and save them as new columns. I tried using matrixStats::rowQuantiles, but it gives an NA value for the row containing NAs even though I set na.rm=TRUE to remove NAs before calculating.

I also noticed that the values for Q1 and Q3 are the same for each row. It's more likely that I'm using the function wrong than that these are actually the same, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

```
#set up data
row1= c(0.001020267, 0.001114546, NA, 0.001038988, 0.0009687599, 0.001052172, NA, NA, 0.001044239,  0.00108163)
row2=c(0.002089891, 0.002180456, 0.002083801, 0.001984546, 0.001968671, 0.002104716, 0.00191239, 0.001899664, 0.001891908, 0.001854954)
row3=c(0.004956524, 0.004559659, 0.004214533, 0.004450447, 0.004310213, 0.004535139, 0.004416997, 0.004174858, 0.004027706, 0.003959555)

df=as.data.frame(rbind(row1,row2,row3))

#apply rowQuantiles
library(matrixStats)
df$Q1=rowQuantiles(as.matrix(df[,],probs=0.25, na.rm=TRUE))
df$Q3=rowQuantiles(as.matrix(df[,],probs=0.75, na.rm=TRUE))

#creates Q1 and Q3 columns
#row1 Q1 = NA Q3 = NA
#row2 Q1 = 0.001854954 Q3 = 0.001854954
#row3 Q1 = 0.003959555 Q3 = 0.003959555
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `as.matrix(df[,]` doesn't have a closing `)` after the `df[,])`

If we change the code to

```
rowQuantiles(as.matrix(df), probs = 0.25, na.rm=TRUE)
#     row1        row2        row3     
#  0.001029628 0.001902845 0.004184777
```

while the OP's code is passing the `probs` and `na.rm` in the `as.matrix` which doesn't need that argument although it didn't show any error, thus, when we get the `rowQuantiles`, it will be using `na.rm = FALSE` by default and the `probs` as the default probs i.e. `seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.25)`

Also, there is no need to specify `df[,]`.  Simply `df` will return the entire dataset including all the rows and the columns

---

It is not clear why the OP created `matrix` (with `rbind`) then converted to `data.frame` and then again to `matrix`.  By default, `rbind` uses the method `rbind.matrix` and creates a `matrix`.  So, we don't really need any transformations back and forth between data.frame and matrix i.e.

```
rowQuantiles(rbind(row1,row2,row3), probs = 0.25, na.rm = TRUE)
#      row1        row2        row3 
#0.001029628 0.001902845 0.004184777
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying how those each work- it was really informative! Switching between matrix and data frame is just because my full data set is a data frame, so I had to make sure that worked too.